# Does following limit exists at infinity?

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a real valued differentiable function on $(0,\infty)$ such that
\begin{align}
|f(x)| &\leq 5 \\
f(x)f'(x) &\leq \sin (x) \qquad \text{on}\, (0, \infty)
\end{align} 
Does limit of $f$ exists at $\infty$ ?

I have solved differential equation $ f(x)f'(x)= \sin (x) $ but my solution at some point not differential. May I have some hint how to proceed?

Comment: Where is the function defined? If, as you say in the first line, $f$ is defined on $(0,1)$, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Uh - there's a family of solutions to $f(x)f'(x)=\sin x$. Some of them are local solutions that can't be extended past a certain interval, while others are smooth everywhere. Can you elaborate on your solution there?

Comment: Sorry! i have edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any function $f$ satisfying the second inequality the limit does *not* exist. Here’s why:

Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}f(x)^2$. Then 
$$g’(x) =f(x)f’(x) \leq \sin(x).$$
Now let $x<y$, then since integrals preserve inequalities we have
$$g(y)-g(x)=\int_x^y g’(s)ds \leq \int_x^y \sin(s)ds=\cos(x)-\cos(y)$$
So
$$g(y)+\cos(y) \leq g(x)+\cos(x)$$
so the function $h$ defined by 
$$h(x)=g(x)+\cos(x)$$
for $x \in (0, \infty)$ is decreasing, and it is bounded below since
$$g(x)+\cos(x) \geq -1$$
so the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)$ exists and is a real number. If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ would exist then clearly it cannot be minus or plus infinity since that would imply $h$ goes to infinity. So the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ exists as well and is a real number, which would give
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)-g(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)- \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$$
clearly a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! Now i think we can drop first condition boundedness of f  because in your proof i have not find any use of that..

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x)=\sqrt{c-2\cos(x)}$ with $1<c<23$ as counter example.

Comment: $2$ should be inside the square root sign and you need $c <\frac {23} 2$.

Comment: @kavi rama murthy agreed!